# active model serializer not showing all attributes of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have an Item. It belongs_to a User. I have an ItemSerializer and a UserSerializer in app/serializers:

```
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :photo

  belongs_to :user
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :authentication_token
end
```

These relationships model the relationships in app/models

When I return an ActiverRecord::Relation of items as json in my controller:

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      @items = Item.where(id: params[:item_ids)
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @items, status: 200}
    end
  end
```

It should be returning the user attributes, including email and authentication_token, as well. But it is only returning the user id:

```
... "relationships":{"user":{"data":{"id":"1","type":"users"}}} ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
render json: @items, include: "**", status: 200
```

In your controller. AMS can be finicky in returning related object attributes so sometimes you need to be explicit about it.

Comment: I don't know if this works or not, but check out my solution. The problem is I was using json_api instead of json for the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I am using active_model_serializers version 0.10.0. In `config/environments/initialzers/active_model_serializer.rb`, I had the following configuration:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

When I changed it to:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json
```

It gave me the attributes of the associations as well, as illustrated from the console:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new( Item.where(id: params[:item_ids), adapter: :json).to_json
```

Comment: adapter json_api supports exact jsonapi standard format, when we change adapter to json, it will give normal format.